# Server unknown issue when creating new SQL view

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sql

I have been following a course on Udemy using GeoServer (my version is 2.12.0). I plug in the same SQL code used in the course but when I click "Guess SQL Parameters", this message shows up:

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = selectItemContainer]]

[image]
[image]

Perhaps it has something to do with Java? This morning I went to start GeoServer and it wouldn't start, so I looked at the startup.bat file and it was looking for a Java file that disappeared from my computer somehow (it wanted Java/jre1.8.0_73; I had jre1.8.0_71 and had just installed jre1.8.0_151, so I changed it to the latter and it started up just fine, but the error message seems to suggest that it's Java related.

Comment: Okay, I'll install the latest version of GeoServer then! Thanks!

Comment: @chrki: you should make this an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RoVo I wasn't sure how to proceed, see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports -- I posted it as an answer now

Answer (score 5):

Geoserver 2.11.3 and 2.12.0 (you are using this one) had a bug with "Guess SQL parameters" that caused it to fail like you described.

This has been fixed in 2.12.1 (released in stable branch) and 2.11.4 (currently only in nightly). You can read the bug report of the Geoserver bug tracker here: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8363

Comment: I wonder if my IT guy installed the new version correctly- I still get that message!

Comment: I still get that message after installing 2.12.1. I'll try 2.11.4 when it comes out next week.